# Hackers exploit Magento e-commerce vulnerability

Tags: patches, security

This blog, [PC world](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2914512/hackers-exploit-magento-ecommerce-vulnerability.html), claims that the hackers are attacking the e-commerce websites. and I should get updated with the latest patch.

> Check Point, which found the flaw, reported it to Magento, which [issued a patch](http://blog.checkpoint.com/2015/04/20/analyzing-magento-vulnerability/) (SUPEE-5344) on Feb. 9. Since Check Point revealed the flaw earlier this week, it appears attackers have picked up on it and are trying to find unpatched applications.

Should I get this patch?

How can I trust this patch?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to install new `patch` its safe & it's necessary to prevent attacks on the site.

You must `install` this on all `Magento` site.

Step to install patch:

1. Download `patch` from [Magento Commerce](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/) and upload to your root directory.
2. Connect your `shell` & run following command after navigate to the root directory of your `Magento` installation, `sh PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh`
3. Clear your `cache` & you are done.

The `alert message` will be still visible in the `admin` until you mark as read.

You can `confirm your patch` from the following site directly.
http://magento.com/security-patch

1. Enter your `store URL` & change `admin` path if it's different 
   If a message appears `SAFE: This site appears to be safe.` Then it's patched successfully.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I get this patch?

Yes and all other patches, which are provided by magento.

> How can I trust this patch?

I prefer to review the patches, then run them locally and deploy them via VCS or whatever system. So you know, what happens, while running the patch.