# Error in check after installing PATCH 5344 successfully

Tags: patches

I applied the PATCH 5344 supree, manually, by going through each file change as mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/sashas777/magento-1.9-patch-1533-5344/commit/c7d5fedcba174d9cacc1d7e375cf0226ccc1f736#diff-eb054b11490ab2f023d8cc5ad9d7b5a1R62)

After successful changes, to test whether the patch is applied or not, I used this magento.com/security-patch link.

This showed me that the site is safe now by showing this message:

[image]

Now after one day (approx.), when I checked again with the same link, It showing me the following message:

[image]

What could be the issue? Is the site is showing wrong or my site is been attacked by hacker again?

Comment: And if it successfully connects and reports you're still vulnerable => http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64930/applied-patches-but-still-getting-a-vulnerable-message/64974#64974 Your hosting provider may also have enabled a WAF filter that blocks it from attempting the exploit. Ask them...

Answer (score 1):

The error message does not mean that the site does not have the patch in place it simply means that the system had issues with connecting to your shop. I think that it could be a network issue or simply a typo when you filled in the form.

Comment: I am sure it is not a typo nor I have any network issues. I am posting here after checking thoroughly.